# org-pomodoro How can I record break times also?

Tags: org-mode

How can I record the pomodoro break times in a separate heading? Every time a pomodoro ends, I would like the break to be automatically recorded under `** Breaks` in my org file.

```
* Work
** Actual Work
:CLOCKING:
-----------------------------> pomodoro is recorded here
:END:

** Breaks
:CLOCKING:
-----------------------------> I would like to record here
:END:
```

[org-pomodoro.el](https://github.com/marcinkoziej/org-pomodoro/blob/master/org-pomodoro.el) is here.

Comment: I don't know anything about `pomodoro` or `pomdoro.el`, but I wanted to point out the existence of [org-pomodoro](https://github.com/marcinkoziej/org-pomodoro) just in case it might be helpful.

Comment: @NickD Yes that is what I'm using and linked. Sorry for the wrong file name. Fixed it now.